# YII CUploadedFile issue

Tags: yii

why below code does not work?

```
$video = new Videos();

$video->photo = CUploadedFile::getInstance($video,'photo');

echo $video->photo->extensionName;
```

nothing comes in $video->photo and it gives error :: Trying to get property of non-object

1) File field is 
   <input type="file" id="photo" name="Video[photo]" />

2) Added enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form

3) Added photo field in model

please help

Comment: i got the error in above post... input box name is changed from Video[photo] to Videos[photo] ... 's' was missing in form field.

Answer (score 0):

you need to be sure you have the CFormModel->rules() has the $photo, told to be a file.